# Foreign key attribute not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When attempting to create an Entity Framework database model using attributes as lined out in [MS Data Developer Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships), I'm unable to add the ForeignKey attribute. Do I need to add another using statement to my code?

Here's a copy of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Tester.Models
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Segment> Segments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Note> segNotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Note
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime notetimestamp { get; set; }
        public string notestring { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`

Supported in .NET framework 4.5 and higher